# Bootstrap Scaffolding @ 3600x1920

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a web application that has a sort of "coordinator" interface. I'd like to be able to support the Eyefinity setup that I work on (which is 3 portrait monitors at **3600x1920**, or **3780x1920** with bezel correction on).

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I think its responsive design feature has what I need, but I'm not sure how to customize it to what I want.

I basically need 3 columns, each ~1200 px wide, but I want those columns to break down to 3 rows when the screen width is less than, say 1920px wide.

Can this be done by adding another class of device to the `responsive.less` set of files?

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

Here's some test screenshots:

[Too wide to fit comfortably on a standard screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ETae.png)

[Same data, perfect at 3600x1920](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvtks.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, that was easier than I expected.

All I had to do was add a class to my top-level row (I called it row-eyefinity) and then add the following CSS to my stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width:3500px) {
    .row-eyefinity > [class*="span"] {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```